# docker-compose setting environment variables which the container cannot retrieve

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Sorry for bringing an old thread up but I feel Aurélien Bottazini would be able to help me here.

Same problem here. I feel I am close to what Aurélien Bottazini said here but not there yet. From my docker-compose file below

```
I already have a built image that I want to run
I would like that env variable (wtmsdemo_customerapi01) to be able to set to the API container that I am spinning up as well.
I am not able to read the environment variable from the docker-compose file below.
```

help ?

---

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: softwaremaker/web-w
    environment:
      - wtmsdemo_customerapi01=http://api/api/values
    ports:
      - "89:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    image: softwaremaker/api-w

  networks:
    default:
      external:
        name: nat
```

Comment: what is the output of `docker exec -it <container-name-softwaremaker/web-w> bash env` ?

Comment: I am running this in a windows docker environment. Would bash work ?

In any case, i can see that the env is written in but I cannot retrieve it from the app (Get.EnvironmentVariables("wtmsdemo_customerapi01"). 

I could do this with docker run -e wtmsdemo_customerapi01=ABC env though...so I am a bit lost here